# How to used Goto statement in MVC3 razor view page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i am Develop MVC3 razor Web application. View page i am try to used goto statement but do not work. How to write or syntax of goto statement in view page or .chtml file please help me.
thank you for advance.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far : )

Comment: ouch, goto?? using goto is programmers hell!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not wanting to use the `goto` keyword and rather navigate to (goto) a `View`.

MVC uses `Controllers` that route `HTTP` requests to `Views`, you will need something like this in your controller:

```
    public ActionResult YourWebPage()
    {
        return View("MyPage");
    }
```

Then you can navigate to the `URL`: `http://YourSite/YourWebPage`

Which will use the View "MyPage" which points to the `.cshtml` file.

As a tutorial, check out: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: @user1643609 you will have to post a new question regarding your viewbag compare problem.  If this answer helped please upvote it and mark it as the answer.

Comment: Hello, I want to use the goto keyword on the View page. So how can I use that?